# Extract embedded files from word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, export

I have word file that I need extract files from unzipping doesn't work as it is not giving out all files and naming is incorrect.
I need to get out 5 type of files (word, excel, power point, rar and .pdf) don't care about others..
Problem is that there are a lot of files that can't be opened as I don't have systems needed for that:
How can I extract these files without opening embedded files:
I have started 3 optional codes but they are nowhere near to finish as I don't have enough knowledge :(

```
Sub ExtractAndSaveEmbeddedFiles()
    Dim objEmbeddedShape As InlineShape
    Dim strShapeType As String, strEmbeddedDocName As String
    Dim objEmbeddedDoc As Object
    With ActiveDocument
        For Each objEmbeddedShape In .InlineShapes
            '  Find and open the embedded doc.
            Set objEmbeddedDoc = objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.Object
            strShapeType = objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.ClassType
            StrPath = "CXXXXPATH"
            OLEFormat.Save (StrPath + OLEFormat.SuggestedExtension)
            Set objEmbeddedDoc = Nothing
        Next objEmbeddedShape
    End With
End Sub
```

```
Sub ExtractAndSaveEmbeddedFiles()
    Dim objEmbeddedShape As InlineShape
    Dim strShapeType As String, strEmbeddedDocName As String
    Dim objEmbeddedDoc As Object
    With ActiveDocument
        For Each objEmbeddedShape In .InlineShapes
            '  Find and open the embedded doc.
            strShapeType = objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.ClassType
            If .OLEFormat.ClassType = "Excel.Sheet" Then
                objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.Open
                '  Initialization
                Set objEmbeddedDoc = objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.Object
                '  Save embedded files with names as same as those of icon label.
                strEmbeddedDocName = objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.IconLabel
                objEmbeddedDoc.SaveAs "XXXXPATH" & strEmbeddedDocName
                objEmbeddedDoc.Close
            End If
            Set objEmbeddedDoc = Nothing
        Next objEmbeddedShape
    End With
End Sub
```

```
Sub ExtractFiles()
    '
    ' ExtractFiles Macro
    '
    '
    Dim shape As InlineShape
    Dim folderName As String
    Dim a As Document
    folderName = "XXXXXPATH"
    For Each shape In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        If (shape.Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject) And (InStr(LCase(shape.OLEFormat.IconLabel), ".docx") > 0) Then
            shape.OLEFormat.Object.SaveAs (folderName & "\" & shape.OLEFormat.IconLabel)
        End If
    Next shape
End Sub
```

Comment: See, for example: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/how-to-extract-embedded-files-from-word-document/6a92bd9a-1ceb-4cf8-bd6f-ebad955cbdc1

Comment: If you don't have the software corresponding to the file types and/or that software can't be automated (has no COM object model) then this is not going to be possible using VBA.

Comment: I've added a solution for Mac to do so:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64157886/how-to-extract-embedded-pdf-from-word-document-in-linux-mac/64157887#64157887